# C++ :: Function to return user input until enter key is pressed

Tags: c++, function, return, getchar

This is definitely NOT the current syntax but just so you'd get the idea :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getWord()
{
    while((c=getchar())!='\n')
    {
        myString.=c;
    }
    return myString;
}

int main(void)
{
    var c=getWord();
    print_f("\nCLast Word:",c);
    return 0;
}
```

Bare in mind that I do not what to break the current line and I'm expecting to get the user input and stay on the same line even after enter key is being pressed.

Comment: simply use std::getline? And why "getWord" if you want to get input until "enter"?

Comment: In most console windows it is extremely likely that the cursor moves down when Enter is pressed. On the other hand, if you instead remove `\n` from the output, nobody will notice the difference.

Comment: eventually it would be "getWord" and "getQuote" it was just an example :D...

Comment: AFAIK, the Windows console only sends the program the input when Enter is pressed, therefore you can't read the input before that happens.

Answer (score 1):

Use std::getline. The function reads one line from an input stream and save it into a string.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    std::getline(std::cin, input); // get input until enter key is pressed
    std::cout << input << std::endl; // print the string
    return 0;
}
```

or you can omit std:: by "using namespace std;"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string input;
    getline(cin, input); // get input until enter key is pressed
    cout << input << endl; // print the string
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Working (almost perfectly) I was using getchar for a reason... I don't want to get a new line after enter key is pressed... I want to stay on the same line

Comment: The standard C++ I/O libraries only have functions that read input from a stream, which means to get a string on a console, enter key should be pressed. If you want to get the input without pressing enter key, you have to use nonstandard functions like _getch() in <conio.h> in Windows.